# Why is JavaScript sometimes viewed as a low level language?

Tags: javascript, definition, low-level

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084045/).

I commonly see people referring to JavaScript as a low level language, especially among users of GWT and similar toolkits.

My question is: why? If you use one of those toolkits, you're cutting yourself from some of the features that make JavaScript so nice to program in: functions as objects, dynamic typing, etc. Especially when combined with one of the popular frameworks such as jQuery or Prototype.

It's like calling C++ low level because the standard library is smaller than the Java API. I'm not a C++ programmer, but I highly doubt every C++ programmer writes their own GUI and networking libraries.

Comment: Ummm...it isn't?

Comment: @Ed: It isn't usually, but it's an attitude that you do see, and seems to be getting more common.

Comment: It isn't *ever*. A low-level language means close to the machine.  Javascript is not close to the machine in any way shape or form.  The best definition for low-level is: "could you write an entire OS kernel it, without any shim between your code and the machine?" If it's yes, you have a low-level language.

Comment: @Christopher:  Yes, thank you :).  Let's see someone deal with hardware interrupts in js :-)

Comment: I suspect this notion of "low-level" comes from a misunderstanding of how and why languages are built. That it's a strict hierarchy, with high-level languages built on mid-level languages in turn built on low-level languages. Which is almost entirely wrong, but assuming that's what you're working from then anything you want to hide with an abstraction becomes "low-level". So these terms get thrown around in places they don't apply, such as translating a high-level language into a high-level language (Java to JavaScript).

Comment: I agree with Christopher, JS isn't low-level by any stretch of imagination. That being said though, I *wish* I could do asynchronous programming easily, and use functions as objects, in C.

Comment: Do you mean "low quality"? Nobody could possibly consider JavaScript as "low level" in the general sense. That's a bit like calling a mousepad "hardware"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a high-level language, given its flexibility (functions as objects, etc.)

But anything that is commonly compiled-to can be considered a low-level language simply because it's a target for compilation, and [there are many languages that can now be compiled to JS](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+as+assembly+language) because of its unique role as the browser's DOM-controlling language.

Among the languages (or subsets of them) that can be compiled to JS:

- Java
- C#
- Haxe
- Objective-J
- Ruby
- Python

Comment: I would argue that the term 'low level' has a lot more to do with how close you are to the hardware layer.  The fact that other languages can be compiled to js is meaningless.

Comment: Rather than 'compiled to' I see is as 'translate to' as C++ used to be translated into C

Comment: Distinguishing between compilers and translators is notoriously tricky.

Comment: While it is definitely true that the view held by people such as Ed Swangren above is true (from that perspective).  However, the people that refer to it as lowlevel are speaking exactly from the perspective that Nosredna describes :-)

Comment: If you consider the DOM as the internal guts of the browser, nothing gets close to it compared to JavaScript. It's the bottom layer.

Comment: @Joel, yeah, if the GWT people aren't thinking of it as the low-level target language for their compiler, I don't know what they _are_ thinking. :-)

Comment: @Nosreda: But that browser sits upon countless layers of abstraction.  I don't know, I can see what you guys are saying in a relative sort of way, but to me, calling js a low level language is pretty laughable.  Of course, I work in a systems group :)

Comment: @Ed, most of the code I've written for money has been assembly language, so I'm not alien to your perspective. :-)

Comment: @Nosredna:  Wow, you're more hardcore than I am!  I mean, it is an interpreted language though, I just can't see how anyone could think...

Comment: @Ed, I've been programming for 30 years. What is "low level" is higher every year. I used to think C was hopelessly slow.

Comment: @Nosrenda:  That is true, I am younger and some of the older guys laugh when I refer to C++ as a low level language :-)

Comment: Besides, V8 and TraceMonkey aren't the typical slow JS interpreters of a couple years ago. It's a crazy world. Even Java is fast now.

Comment: Speed does not make a language a low level language.  C# is very fast (relatively), but I would not consider it 'low level'.

Comment: Funny thing about the DOM... near as i can tell, it was designed as an API to be used by Java - there are vast portions of it that make little or no sense from a Java*Script* perspective. Indeed, many of the most successful JS DOM libraries of the past few years have been those that go out of their way to *hide* the intricacies of the DOM from client scripts.

Comment: @Ed: C# is high level. It compiles to IL or JavaScript--the low level languages. :-)

Comment: but JS can also be compiled itself to other languages, namely .NET bytecode

Answer (score 5):

Answering a question that says "why is something sometimes called X..." with "it's not X" is completely side stepping the question, isn't it?

To many people, "low-level" and "high-level" are flexible, abstract ideas that apply differently when working with different systems.  To people that are not all hung up on the past (there is no such thing as a modern low-level language to some people) the high-ness or low-ness of a language will commonly refer to how close to the target machine it is.  This includes virtual machines, of which a browser is now days.  Sorry to all the guys who pine for asm on base hardware.

When you look at the browser as a virtual machine, javascript is as close to the (fake) hardware as you get.  That is the viewpoint that many who call javascript "low-level" have.  I think it's a pointless distinction to make and people shouldn't get hung up on what is low and what is high.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people say this because the objects and structures provided in JavaScript are about as simple as you can get. To develop any sort of real functionality, you have to use an external library. Low level is a bad way to put this, because it already has a meaning in computer science. A better way to say it may be that it's without built-in libraries.

Compare this with Java, where the actual language really doesn't do a whole lot. Trying making an array without an ArrayList, or access the file system without the IO libraries. Most languages are more than just the basics, they come with this extra functionality.

With JavaScript, the only real power we get comes from the APIs that are introduced by the browsers and aren't part of the language. Things like DOM manipulation and Ajax are supplied by the browser.

It may be better to summarize all of this by saying that with a language like Java, you can get started doing some serious work without having to download third-party libraries, but with JavaScript, you either have to download a library or write a library of your own.

Comment: A library is useful if you want to abstract DOM calls.

But I find JavaScript more than capable for writing small to medium apps without any kind of library. Being able to return objects and arrays that you create on-the-fly drastically simplifies some types of problems.

I ported a project from JavaScript to C and realized then just how powerful JavaScript is.

Comment: DOM itself is a third-party library. I tried to make the point in what I just wrote that JavaScript in the browser comes with a third-party library: the DOM, BOM, and Ajax APIs.

Answer (score 2):

"Low" here has the same meaning as in the sentences "The number of casualties suffered in the first world war was low," and "Reduced-fat ice cream is low in calories."  It makes sense when there's an obvious point of comparison, but out of context, it is simply absurd.

Answer (score 1):

I don't view javascript as a low level language. A lot of functionality and user experience boosters are provided by it. Maybe others may view it as such simply because users can turn it off in their browser options, but it's a hugely robust language that virtually runs the web on virtually all types of browsers...

Answer (score 1):

It's not, it may be as low-level as you can get in normal browser programming, but its on par with functional languages like Scheme or Python.

I think the great lacks of Javascript are lack of name spaces or packaging and no threads

Comment: Lack of threads is not a language issue but an implementation issue. Thus, the web workers of Gears and HTML5.

Comment: it's hard to separate a language from it's runtime - there's not threading model in the javascript runtime or the language definition. the same holds for Scheme. Python on the other hand does threads all the way down

Comment: That's true But JavaScript doesn't just exist in browsers.

Comment: But you further my point - other Javascript definitions and implementations don't thread either - eg. ECMAscript or Javascript in Rhino

Comment: What do you think about web workers? They allow you to spin off background scripts that run in parallel.

Comment: Webworkers are running in a separate process, it's a neat trick the Gears guys pulled off but definitely not threads. You basically need to do IPC between them.

Answer (score 1):

It's low-level compared to the GWT and similar toolkits, but it's not a low-level language in the larger scheme of things.  The features it offers are very high-level: closures, dynamic typing, and prototypical inheritance are just a few examples of its high-level features.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's kinda the question here: when these high-level features don't exist in the language+toolkit being used to "compile" to it, how can you really consider that language/toolkit to be of a higher-level...

Answer (score 0):

It's considered to be low level by a number of people who prefer writing java to generate javascript then writing javascript(ie they dislike it fairly or unfairly). A lot of people complain about java these days but despite the lack of static type checking most people would probably consider ruby and python easier to write in most cases (java being a fairly simple static language-which are much harder to design well without large built-in feature sets then a simple dynamic language).

Few people would call python or ruby low level compared to java and if people were forced to target a python or ruby vm its hard to imagine that a java to python/ruby compiler would become as popular as gwt.

In closing javascript has an image problem(people sometimes think of languages as getting more difficult as they become more low level and vice versa).